# How to insert big sql query in a column in Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle

Is their any way to insert my below SQL query as a record in table called demo

**My table DDL:**

```
create table DEMO
(
  v_sql clob
);
```

**My below sample query need to be inserted into above table for column v_sql**

```
select * DEMO.EMP where name in (
'ABC',
'VILAS'
'XYZ'
) and DTS='DD-MON-YYYY' and select * from ( select * from DEMO.EMP where id=1)
```

Any method to do this

Note : even the query which i given is small.
It might be big can contain query of 50 to 100 lines [ more then > 4000 character ]
combined with joins and all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better solution will be have your string within q'{}'. In this way you need not to escape any single quote(') within your data:

```
insert into demo values(
q'{select * DEMO.EMP where name in (
'ABC',
'VILAS'
'XYZ'
) and DTS='DD-MON-YYYY' and select * from ( select * from DEMO.EMP where id=1)}')
```

You can also escape the single quotes (') with another single quote('') before it like below:

```
insert into demo values(
'select * DEMO.EMP where name in (
''ABC'',
''VILAS''
''XYZ''
) and DTS=''DD-MON-YYYY'' and select * from ( select * from DEMO.EMP where id=1)')
```

Above queries will insert your desired data in the mentioned table. I will suggest to use first one.

Comment: what if i want to insert this one `DT='%InData%'` as it is in above query

Comment: what i want to insert special character as it is => $  # & % ( ) ! @

Comment: @codeholic24 Nothing special until your text will have the closing delimiter (`}` in the above example) followed by single quotation mark: this sequence should not be in your literal `}'`. If it can have this, you need to select another delimiter for your literal, check [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-1824CBAA-6E16-4921-B2A6-112FB02248DA) about this.

Comment: As @astentx mentiond only `}'` can cause you trouble. The characters you mentioned will be fine.

Comment: @codeholic24 please accept this answer if it helped you to solve your problem.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur Thanks for your solution it work like charm .. I voted it . one more help I need from you as No one is coming with solution ...you see the above question the record get inserted to table … is their any way to call that query as a parameter to store procedure dynamically and execute return output from query             I have posted it as a separate question can you check how it can be achieved : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66858147/how-to-pass-parameter-dynamically-to-stored-procedure-in-oracle

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur  see this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66858147/how-to-pass-query-as-a-parameter-to-store-procedure-and-return-output-in-oracle

Comment: Will try to find a solution.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur  are you able to find solution its really important ..?