# How to pass query as a parameter to store procedure and return output in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to implement this below approach where I have a table called `EMP`.

That table contains three columns: `CNUM, CD, O_SQL`

- `CNUM` => will contain some code as mentioned in below image => `AXX`
- `CD` => will contain some code as mentioned in below image => `A`
- `O_SQL` => will contain a SQL query

Now I want to create one function that will trigger a query and fetch the `O_SQL` query into some variable.

Like I pass this following query as parameter to function =>

```
select O_SQL from EMP where CNUM = 'AXX'
```

will get me result into variable

```
z = 'select * from EMP where rownum = 1;'
```

This result query stored in variable `z` should be passed to a stored procedure as shown here:

```
PrintOutput(z)

print z
```

My output should be :

[image: Output]

How to implement this approach?

[image]

Comment: I would get familiar with types Oracles and functions that return tables -- the pseudo code in  your question looks like you're trying to create a python esque data frame.   Start with this page - excellent help -  https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/when-is-a-function-like-a-table-when-its-a-table-function

Comment: @irnerd   can you help me with code how to create .. i refer the above link but bit difficult as  I am not good in SQL

Comment: look at EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

Comment: @OldProgrammer how to do that ? Execute immediate

Comment: You read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/EXECUTE-IMMEDIATE-statement.html#G).

Comment: Why `noneditionable`, out of interest?